# IntelliJ is producing "Server access Error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection" when creating a new Play framework project

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

My operating system is Fedora 28 running on VMware. I'm working behind a corporate so I have to use [px-proxy](https://github.com/genotrance/px) to connect Fedora and other tech running inside it to the internet (Docker, DNF, etc). I have configured the proxy settings in Intellij already.

So I went ahead and created a new Play project in IntelliJ. But when building it produces the following error?

```
Error while importing sbt project:

Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.17  (this may take some time)...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17

==== local: tried

/home/clover/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/ivys/ivy.xml

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

/home/clover/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/jars/sbt.jar

==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried

file:////home/clover/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/ivys/ivy.xml

==== local-preloaded: tried

file:////home/clover/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

file:////home/clover/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar

==== Maven Central: tried

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17: not found
(see /home/clover/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.17

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar

==== sbt-maven-releases: tried

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar

==== sbt-maven-snapshots: tried

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom

-- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17!sbt.jar:

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar

==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/ivys/ivy.xml

==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/ivys/ivy.xml

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.17: not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
Server access Error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom

Server access Error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar

Server access Error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.pom

Server access Error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/sbt-0.13.17.jar

Server access Error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/ivys/ivy.xml

Server access Error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.17/ivys/ivy.xml


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
```

Things I have tried before opening IntelliJ:

I set `JAVA_HOME` in `.bash_profile`:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk"

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

I exported the environment variables for Java's proxy:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=myprxhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=myprxhost  -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1"
```

`echo $JAVA_OPTS` produces `-Dhttp.proxyHost=myprxhost  -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=myprxhost  -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1`

I downloaded the cloud services certificate file that my employer issues. Then I entered the following command:

```
sudo keytool -import -alias CloudServices -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file cloud_services.cer
```

How can I work my way to fixing this issue?